# How to update unrelated component in react without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Suppose I have 2 components A and B which are not linked (by props), but which are linked by the database. component A has a button that changes the data in the database.

I want component B (only with A) to render when the database changes. The problem is, that when the component A mutate the database, the page needs to be refreshed in order for component B to be updated.

It's may be a weird question but I'm still a beginner in React.

Comment: Sounds like they *should* be connected by a state at a higher level; there are many ways that could be implemented (context, redux, plain state as props, etc)

Comment: Yeah, seems like a good place to use [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: thank you for you response guys, I will check context API then